# Strange behaviour with asp.net mvc action filters AttributeUsage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action filter with the following signature

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class UnitOfWorkAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
```

According to MSDN:

> The AllowMultiple property indicates whether multiple instances of
>   your attribute can exist on an element. If set to true, multiple
>   instances are allowed; if set to false (the default), only one
>   instance is allowed.

In MVC the behaviour seems a bit strange. When I decorated an action with this attribute, I found that the `OnActionExecuting` method of the filter was executed twice.

The filter was only declared on the action, not on the controller, and I had cleared any global filters. Could someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Is just _AllowMultiple_ that will cause _OnActionExecuting_ to be called twice, or did you indeed decorate your action with two instances of the attribute?

Comment: @Codo, no I don't need multiple instances so setting AllowMultiple to false resolves the problem, but it doesn't explain it. Possibly a bug in asp.net mvc?

Comment: the action does really not fired twice ? only the attribute ?

Comment: Is it possible that two actions really did fire?  Transparent redirect, for example?

Comment: The action method is executed once. The *OnActionExecuting* method of the ActionFilter fires twice.

Comment: I would be interested in replicating this behaviour; can you make a sample project available for download?

Comment: Do you have a custom base controller class with a filter on that method or any other unusual cases? Can you replicate with a brand new MVC 3 project?

Comment: I created an attribute with AllowMultiple = true and it doesn't display this behavior.  It only got called once.  You can see the attribute here: http://pastebin.com/YtVX1YX5.

Answer (score 33):

I encountered the same problem. (I installed a global filter (just once) and discovered that its `IActionFilter` and `IResultFilter` methods were being called twice for each request. The `filterContext.HttpContext` object being passed to these methods was exactly the same for both calls.)

This turned out to be due to using [`Html.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457.aspx) in the view. It appears (from looking at the call stack) that calling `Html.Action` reentrantly processes the child action method (during the processing of the initial action method) and the filters get invoked for both.

You can detect this situation by checking the `filterContext.IsChildAction` property.

Comment: It's great that this worked, but why is it doing it. I'm thinking back to all of the apps that used custom action filters and am concerned.

Comment: filterContext.IsChildAction saved lots of lives. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the `OnActionExecuting` method from my custom action filter class executing twice too.

At some point I added this to my `Application_Start` method in the global.asax.cs file:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new MyCustomActionFilter());
```

Apparently, my action filter was already added to the `Filters` collection which was leading to the double call to `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted`. So that line in the applicaton_start was not needed.